# can not use sso with aws client vpn

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, aws-vpn, aws-sso

I have provisioned AWS Client VPN by using this [terragrunt](https://github.com/DNXLabs/terraform-aws-client-vpn) module. I have two SAML providers and provided both SAML providers' arn urls in VPN configuration.

I implemented SSO for VPN login but I'm facing `bad input HTTP status 400` error when I tried to connect to VPN. Is there anyone who faced this issue before?